# Brew does not work when installing (hashcat)

Tags: macos, homebrew, hashcat

I had this problem... so i tried to install hashcat via homebrew, but i got this error back:

command used:
 `brew install hashcat`

````
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "hashcat".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.```
````

Comment: What makes you think it *should* be installable via brew?

Comment: Youtube and online blogs

Comment: Does the official hashcat documentation or brew repository concur?

Comment: How do I install it otherwise

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Have you tried reading the fine manual? https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#installation

Comment: I tried, but it returns an error: `sudo: apt-get: command not found`

Comment: Nvm - you need kali for that^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced a similar issue in homebrew as below,

```
Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps
```

had run this command to update the branch as master, which fixed the issue:

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

For troubleshooting brew the following command helps:
***brew doctor***